# LinqInstantFeedbackSource not refreshing the contents of XtraGrid

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, devexpress, datacontext

I've used LinqInstantFeedbackSource to bind large amount of data to XtraGrid. Every time data is inserted, I want it to be displayed on the grid. However, I found out lately that as the data grows, the LinqInstantFeedbackSource or DataContext object couldn't help load the data on the XtraGrid instantly. To my surprise, the new data is displayed after waiting for some time or restarting the application.

Turning off the DataContext.ObjectTrackingEnabled option throws an exception on InsertOnSubmit.

What is the workaround solution for this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "new data"? Is this data that was added by another route?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. There is a separate winform on which users will be inserting/updating/deleting data. When they save/update data, the system will take them to another form that contains the XtraGrid.

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q360749

Comment: Aron, I've checked that already. For some reason, disabling the tracking feature didn't work for me

Comment: It throws an exception on InsertOnSubmit when I turn off the DataContext ObjectTrackingEnabled

Comment: I believe that is assuming your insert is done on a different DataContext. Remember EF contexts should be short lived.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36978/discussion-between-aby-and-aron)